# Correctly get access to nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, properties

I have the JS-object, that in Chrome's console looks as folllow:

```
data: Object
 comparisonType: "IN"
 dateValue: ""
 numericalValue: 0
 screeningCriterionId: "-4"
 screeningField.displayName: "Prop1"
 screeningField.fieldName: "Prop2"
 screeningField.groupName: "Prop3"
 screeningField.type: "MULTI"
 value: null
```

And I need to read the  `screeningField.displayName: "Prop1"`  from this object , but 
trying to execute in console this  `myObject.screeningField.displayName` I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

How to solve my problem ?

Comment: If this is indeed what you see in your console, then apparently the dot is actually included in the key name: try `myObject['screeningField.displayName']`

Comment: This does not look like JavaScript. What is your JavaScript code you use to initialize the object?
@lanzz: incorrect, the error says `screeningField` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Cerbrus: of course it does, because it is.

Comment: Cerbrus, I'm getting this object from another code, which I can't watch to define how it initializes.

Comment: @lanzz, oh right, since `screeningField` doesn't exist, the only other option with that object structure would be that the dot is included in the key name?

Comment: @Cerbrus No, the dot is included in the key name because _the console shows it that way_. It is also not displaying any key named `screeningField`, so yes, that key obviously does not exist. Try `console.dir({ foo: { bar: 1 }, 'foo.bar': 1 });` and observe the difference in the presentation of the `foo` key and the `foo.bar` key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the dot is actually included in the key name, try:

```
myObject['screeningField.displayName']
```